# Max thread ID on Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, c++11, redhat, rhel

Is there a maximum C++ thread ID on Linux? So I'm using std::thread and I call get_id(), is there an upper bound on what the number could be? I thought I had found 2^16 but that seemed to be the max number of Linux processes?

This would be a red-hat distro.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: @Barmar I have a data structure which I would like to put in an array and each thread accesses its own copy. To do this I need to know the upper bound on thread ID.

Comment: This will be a huge array, and most of it will be empty. I think it would be better to use a `std::map`

Comment: @Barmar to know whether it would be a huge array or not I need to know what the max thread ID is :) And it doesn't matter if most of it is empty, the CPU will only load the cache lines/pages I use.

Comment: Since every process is a thread, it will be at least the number of processes, so it's at least 2^16. That's pretty big.

Comment: The function `get_id` returns an instance of [class thread::id](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id). What number are you talking about?